# Missing Moodle Admintration block in Afterburner

Tags: themes, moodle

Please I changed my default theme to the Afterburner theme on my Bitnami Moodle 2.6 which in is installed on my laptop. My question is? Can any one help me find site administration Block? I cant find the site administration block again. How can I get it to show up and it cant how do I uninstall the Afterburner theme without site administration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change theme via direct link in administration panel: [moodle web path]/theme/index.php

Another way - simply delete "afterburner" folder from moodle "theme" directory (delete or move, not rename). Moodle automatically set another theme.